# How to make changing images on an interval, based on Line-Of-Action

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remake the system shown on https://line-of-action.com/practice-tools/face-expression-practice where you can select a variety of options, then a time interval, and submit, which then it narrows down to specific images to show and then randomly presents the images and changes after the selected amount of time, I'll send my html and css below, however I don't know at all how to do this so getting some help would be heavily appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Line Of Action: Db Edition</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fahad-top margintestheader">
  <div class="fahad-bar bgnavbar fahad-card">
    <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item fahad-small"><img src="images/Logo.png"></a>
    <div class="fahad-left" style="margin-top:60px; font-size: large">
      <a href="index.html" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a>
      <a href="About/index.html" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i> About</a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="fahad-bar-item text-color" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
  
<div>
  <h2 style="margin-left:70px;text-decoration:bold;">Faces & Expressions Tool</h2>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:50px;">
  <ul>
  <h2>1. What do you want to draw?</h2>
  <h3>Gender: </h3>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Gender" id="happy" />Male</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Gender" id="happy" />Female</li>
    
  <h3>Expressions:</h3>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Expression" id="happy" />Happy</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Expression" id="Angry" />Angry</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Expression" id="Goofy" />Goofy</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Expression" id="Serious" />Serious</li>

  <h3>Style: </h3>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Style" id="Shintani" />Naohiro Shintani</li>
    
  <h2>2. What time interval?</h2>
  <h3>Time Interval: </h3>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Time" id="30s" />30 Sec</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Time" id="60s" />60 Sec</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Time" id="2m" />2 Min</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Time" id="5m" />5 Min</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="Time" id="10m" />10 Min</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="fahad-button" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left:20px;">Submit</button>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.margintestheader{
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logostuff{
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.bgnavbar{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color:white;
  padding-left: 41px;
  padding-right: 34px;
}
.headtextstuff{
  font-family: 'Museo-300', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #269394;
}
.textstuffhaha{
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 0px 8px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #2693943;
}
.buttonCatalog{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#divIdProduct{
  margin-top:50px;
}
.fahad-small{
  width:60%;
  height:60%
}
.fahad-small2{
  width:57%;
  height:57%
}
.fahad-top{
  top:0
}
.fahad-bar{
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
}
.fahad-bar-item{
  padding:25px 16px;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  border:none;
  display:block;
  outline:0
}
.fahad-card{
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
}
.fahad-right{
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}
.fahad-left{
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
}
.fahad-white{
  color:white;
}
.text-color{
  color:#269394;
}
.fahad-upper{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fahad-column {
  float: left;
  width: 49.2%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fahad-row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.fahad-container{
  width: 500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.fahad-container img{
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.fahad-button {
  background-color: #269394;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

I have a database of images sorted and ready, I just need to learn how to make these radio buttons work to narrow them down and once that's done, do the actual images changing

Comment: there is no starting `<i>`-tags in your HTML

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Why would I need to put <i>? isnt that for italics?

Comment: there is a closing `</i>` at the end of every `<a>`-element, but not an opening tag

Comment: @Rek you have closing `i` tags, but don't have opening ones. Your html is invalid.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski oh thats accidental, must've been left over after i changed my code

Comment: I deleted them on my source code, right now I just want to know how to copy the system shown in that site

Comment: Read about JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction